# Paste text into vb label on formload

Tags: vb.net, label, paste

I'm trying to write a basic net tools program, and I'm sure there already is one out there. I'm writing a vb program to do various cmd commands, and I'm trying to get it to copy the IP config command data and then past it into a label on a form_load. I haven't been able to find any results for a pasting clipboard text at all. Thanks in advance
Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Clipboard.GetText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Label1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text)
End Sub
```